# How to Import an .csv format file into openproject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After setting up the apache server When we choose the .csv file to be imported I get the following error message

```
NoMethodError in ProductImportsController#create 
undefined method `new' for :CSV:Symbol
```

My product_imports_controller.rb

```
class ProductImportsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product_import = ProductImport.new
  end

  def create
    @product_import = ProductImport.new(params[:product_import])
    if @product_import.save
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Imported products successfully."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You want to upload csv file right?

Comment: yes. for now im working  on csv

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'csv'    
class ProductImportsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product_import = ProductImport.new
  end

  def create
    csv_text = File.read(params[:product_import])
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
    csv.each do |row|
      ProductImport.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

For more help read this..

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: It throw backs different error     NameError in ProductsController#import

uninitialized constant Product::Csv

Comment: where you need to parse CSV 'ProductImportsController' or 'ProductsController'?

Comment: i need to parse file on ProductImportsController

Comment: i don't have enough badges i am new to ruby on rails if i share you git code link will that be useful!!!

Comment: You can copy Error Log and paste here

Comment: TypeError in ProductImportsController#create

no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess into String